# Python importing from it's own module/package?

Tags: python, python-3.x, module

I was looking over the python source code for AWS-DataWrangler and I came across something interesting. In line 10 of their top level **init**.py file I see the following line

`from awswrangler import athena, catalog, cloudwatch, db, emr, exceptions, quicksight, s3, sts  # noqa`

[https://github.com/awslabs/aws-data-wrangler/blob/master/awswrangler/**init**.py#L10](https://github.com/awslabs/aws-data-wrangler/blob/master/awswrangler/__init__.py#L10)

How are they importing from their own module here? They don't seem to be messing with `sys.path.append` anywhere I can see.

Comment: This is a thing you can do. Why would they need to mess with `sys.path`?

Comment: This is a standard feature for packages. Typically, a package will consist of multiple modules and there may be imports between them. You could import the module directly, but by importing from 'yourself', you abstract away from where an item actually lives, which is often a good thing.

Comment: @Grismar thanks for the quick run down. So if I were creating my own package I could use the same strategy right out of the box without any setup?

Comment: Yes, pretty much, provided you set things up correctly inside your package - there's lots of questions around that on SO, but I'd give it a try and ask on SO if you run into some unique issue.